# while uploading a image using php and mysql: Warning: file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty

Tags: php, mysql, image-uploading

when i am trying to upload a image to photos folder i am having this type of warning msg i dont know what to.. 
**This is my php file**

```
if (!isset($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])) {
    echo "";
    }else{
    $file=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    $image= mysql_real_escape_string(addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])));
    $image_name= addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);

            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],"photos/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"]);

            $location="photos/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"];

            $save=mysql_query("insert into add values('$location')") or die("can not insert");
            exit();                 
    }
```

**This is my html code**

```
<form method="POST" action='ap.php' enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input name="image" id="image" type="file" />
<input type='submit' name='Add' value='Add'  />
</form>
```

Comment: Why `$image= mysql_real_escape_string(addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])));` is required??You are not using `$image` anywhere.!

Comment: First read file_get_contents ???

Answer (score 1):

No need the following lines:

```
$image= mysql_real_escape_string(addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])));
$image_name= addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
```

Just removed it and test it will work. You are checking the first if condition its enough.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to escape thing. Just do like,

```
if (!isset($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])) {
    echo "Image not selected ";
  }

else
{
    $file=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name']; // temporary name
    $image_name= $_FILES['image']['name']; // original file name

     move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],"photos/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"]);

     $location="photos/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"];
     $query = "Write your query here...";
     $save=mysqli_query($connection, $query);
     if($save)
      {
        // success...do whatever you want
       }
     else
      {
         // executes when save fails
       }      
    }
```

**WARNING :**

`mysql_` is deprecated. Migrate to `mysqli_` or `PDO`. Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection.

Answer (score 1):

Your code working fine, Please check for permission as well for 'photos' must be writable. You can also remove following line as it's have no effect.

```
$image= mysql_real_escape_string(addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])));
```

Please paste full code as well may be some issue with your connection string or other code.

Comment: Please do not write comment as answer

Answer (score 0):

No need of escaping the file `name` & `tmp_name`. Simply do -

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],"photos/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"]);

$location="photos/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"];

$save=mysql_query("insert into add values('$location')") or die("can not insert");
exit();
```

Answer (score 0):

**After removing these two lines. It works fine**

```
$image= mysql_real_escape_string(addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])));
$image_name= addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
```